# n-deep, directory-like structure possible with vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

I'm trying to model a `windows-explorer`-like filesystem with Vue Router. It will have folders, which can have child folders, and/or child items.

Ideally, I would like to use route params to accomplish this, as in:

/projectId/:projectId/items/:folderId/:childFolderId/:childFolderId/.../item/:itemId

Where there could be n-number of `:childFolderId`s. If I could access these `:folderId` params as an array, it would be very simple to set up breadcrumbs correctly, which I think is a key part of this.

Is this possible with vue-router? I've run into limitations on requiring unique, named params.

Thank you.